# SQL Server Objects

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

What is the right order in which we should create SQL Server objects? (This is for the installer order)?

I assume that the right order is

1. Schemas
2. Tables
3. Views
4. Functions
5. SPs

But however, I am confused, what if a View references a function? And, what if a function references a View?

Comment: no, the SPs will come before Functions

Comment: @kalyan - SPs can use Functions so I would put Functions before SPs. Functions can also be used in views and in tables as calculated columns or in triggers so the order of when functions should be generated is not a absolute. It depends on where the function is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no "generic" order in which you can create objects (you missed e.g. a CHECK constraint on a table that may use a function). If you want it 100% right, you need to analyse your specific set of database objects and ensure that they're created in an appropriate order, by analysing the individual dependencies.

---

As a more straightforward example, views can access table-valued functions. But table-valued functions may be based on views. So doing all of either first wouldn't always work.

---

Stored procedures can be created quite early in the process, thanks to [Deferred Name Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx). This is the only positive thing to be said for it.

Comment: Thanks...! We are using TFS for database objects and its deployment...finding dependancy and making a sequential deployment is difficult for us...for now, we have decided not to use views in tabled valuded functions to get around this problem!